# How to change text in element HTML after AJAX response?

Tags: angularjs

I have some HTML elements on page like as:

```
<div ng-click="Add()">1</div>
<div ng-click="Add()">2</div>
<div ng-click="Add()">3</div>
```

How I can change text inside `<div>` after click `Add()` and AJAX response?
I tried to do this on Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using static text for **1**, **2** and **3** you could bind these to something like

```
<div ng-click="Add()">{{options.one}}</div>
<div ng-click="Add()">{{options.two}}</div>
<div ng-click="Add()">{{options.three}}</div>
```

This way Angular will watch if any of those change on every `$digest`.
You can then dynamically set **options.one**, **options.two** and **options.three** and they will update accordingly.

Also, considering how alike your `div` elements are, you should consider putting these in an `ng-repeat` over the **options** object, as in

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in options" ng-click="Add()">{{value}}</div>
```

And have your JS look something like this for starters:

```
 $scope.options = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3
}
```

This is just one way to go about things. You could write a custom directive as well if you are accustomed with something like that, depending on your needs, but this is the easy route.

Comment: In responde AJAX how I can change `{{value}}`?

Comment: You just need to change the **options** object. For example if you would say ```$scope.options.four = 4``` automatically a new ```div``` will be created with the value **4**